# Images won't load in Flickity unless I resize the browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, flickity

I'm working on a project and for whatever reason my images within Flickity slides are loading only when the browser gets slightly resized. Here's my website: /

I have resize set to true in Flickity so I'm not sure what the issue is here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit: problem is solved!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've reported the issue here: https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/1077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to add imagesLoaded in your flickity options and include the images loaded flickity library.

https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#imagesloaded

Comment: This is incorrect (github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/1077).

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else runs into this and imagesLoaded doesnt make a difference for you, this was my solution:

If you happen to be loading this slider inside a modal that on button click, the modal changes from display:none to display: block -- this will also give you the error of needing to resize the screen to make the carousel work.

To fix this, use opacity: 0 instead of display:none on the hidden modal. When the button is clicked, change the modal to opacity:1.

Answer (score 1):

To also add to Kelly's answer. If you have flickity in a modal and changing the opacity isn't an option (i.e. in my case I use the same model for both garllery display and mobile navigation, toggling the display of each feature). You can also destroy the flickity variable and re-initialise. For example in my event handler I have:

```
if (/* condition for closing */) {
  event.preventDefault();
  lightbox.classList.remove('visible');
  flckty.destroy()
  lightboxCar.style.display = "none";
}

else if (/* condition for opening carousel */) {
  lightboxCar.style.display = "initial";
  var pageImgs = document.querySelector("main").getElementsByTagName("img");
  flckty = new Flickity( '#lightbox-carousel', {
    // options
    "cellAlign": 'center',
    });
```

where `lightboxCar` is the carousel item on the page.

Comment: you're the MVP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe opacity will not perfect for you, Use this way if you like :

```
.hide{
    transform: translateY(-1000em);
    position: absolute;
}

.show{
    transform: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

toggle this class using JQuery or JS...

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to load the gallery dynamically and opacity is not the best option for your project, try the *resize* method after loading, or in your open event handler like this:

```
$('.open--modal').on( 'click', function() {
    $carousel.flickity('resize');
});
```

read more https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#resize

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is old but i found a better solution(i think): instead of use opacity use a class with `display:none` and after that you removed the class use `setInterval(() => {swiper.resize()}, 1);`. It works perfectly in my case.